# Error (150) Generated By An SQL Script?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a table on MySQL using an SQL script and the MySQL database keeps on giving me error 150. I've tried the following code in both Navicat and MySQL Workbench and both give an 150 error.

It appears that this is a foreign key problem but i cant actually see what the problem with my code is and was wondering if more expereinced DB users would have any inkling to the problem?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
CREATE TABLE `network_invites` (
`invite_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`invite_From` int(11) NOT NULL,
`invite_Network` int(11) NOT NULL,
`invite_NetCreator` int(11) NOT NULL,
`invite_Message` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`invite_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`invite_ID`),
KEY `invite_From` (`invite_From`),
KEY `invite_Network` (`invite_Network`),
KEY `invite_NetCreator` (`invite_NetCreator`),
CONSTRAINT `network_invites_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`invite_From`) REFERENCES `users`     (`user_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `network_invites_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`invite_Network`) REFERENCES `networks` (`network_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `network_invites_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`invite_NetCreator`) REFERENCES `networks` (`network_Creator`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I cant see what the FK problem is, those fields do exist on the DB and they are of the same datatype.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are they all int(11) precisely?

Comment: The 3 FKs must be exactly the same as in the related table, that is `int(11) NOT NULL`.  If those definitions differ in the related tables, you'll get the 150 err.

Comment: Michael for testing I created dummy tables with exactly the same name/type , and then tried creating table network_invites , however still getting 150 error

Answer (score 0):

I think the workaround is :

1. create the table without constraints
2. add constraints using ALTER TABLE

again , this is a workaround , and would love to hear from people@mysql or someone more experienced

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 2 Table Types are both InnoDB. Also make sure your Primary and Foreign keys are all Unsigned.

All these settings can be changed in NaviCat using the "Design Table" option.

I've come across this problem many times, and this does the trick 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have indexes on `users.user_ID`, `networks.network_ID` and `networks.network_Creator` and the types of the columns should be exactly the same as in the `network_invites` table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a typo:

```
CONSTRAINT `network_invites_ibfk_2` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`invite_Network`) 
  REFERENCES `networks` (`network_ID`)       ---<--- either here
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

CONSTRAINT `network_invites_ibfk_3` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`invite_NetCreator`) 
  REFERENCES `networks` (`network_Creator`)  ---<--- or here (more probable)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Your `networks` table Primary Key is probably `network_ID` and not `network_Creator`.